# Mostrar submenu oculto

Tags: css, html5

Estoy empezando a aprender a desarrollar paginas web y tengo un problema con CSS que no logro resolver.

**Tengo un submenu que no logro mostrar cuando paso el mouse encima del primer `list item` del menú**

Este es mi código:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="bitacora.php">Tickets</a></li>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="ticketnuevo.php">Nuevo Ticket</a></li>
  </ul>
  <li><a href="pingsrv.php">Probar Conexion</a></li>
</ul>
```

Este es mi CSS, pero **quiero definir estos estilos que sean exclusivos del "menu"**.

```
ul {
    /*Quita el simbolo de la lista (cuadro, punto, numero)*/
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #377ADE;
}

li {
    /*hace que las pestañas se alinien hacia la izquierda*/
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    /*color del link o texto*/
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    /*El primero determina el largo, el segundo que tan separados estan*/
    padding: 12px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/*Cuando se pasa el mouse por envima cambia de color*/
li a:hover {
    background-color: #FF0049;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

/*Esconde el submenu ul */
ul ul {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu menú está mal construido, el segundo `ul`, o sea el submenú debe ir dentro del `li` Tickets, es la forma de anidar listas dentro de listas:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="bitacora.php">Tickets</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="ticketnuevo.php">Nuevo Ticket</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="pingsrv.php">Probar Conexion</a></li>
</ul>
```

Para mostrar el submenú tienes que cambiar el display del `ul` al pasar por encima del `li` Tickets:

```
li:hover ul {display:block}
```

Si quieres que los estilos solo se apliquen a este ul en concreto debes identificarlo de alguna forma, con una clase o un id.

Al final quedaría algo así:

```css
#menu {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #377ADE;
  float: left;
}

#menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

#menu li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#menu li:hover a{
  background-color: #FF0049;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

#menu ul {
  display: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  width:400px;
}

#menu li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul id="menu">
  <li><a href="bitacora.php">Tickets</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="ticketnuevo.php">Nuevo Ticket</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="pingsrv.php">Probar Conexion</a></li>
</ul>
```

He cambiado el `hover` de los enlaces a los `li` para que no entrara en conflicto con el efecto de mostrar el submenu y algunos otros ajustes de estilos.

Comment: Excelente muchas gracias, ya entendi el error del diseño del menu, seguire practicando y adaptare tu codigo a mi web, saludos!

Answer (score 1):

prueba con `li:hover > ul {display:block;}`

te adjunto un ejemplo

https://jsfiddle.net/fzura/r5k789fr/

Saludos

```css
#Menu ul {display:none;}
#Menu { list-style:none;}
#Menu li:hover > ul {display:block;}
```

```html
<ul id="Menu">
     <li><a href="#">menu 1 </a></li>
     <li><a href="#">menu 2 </a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">sub 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">sub 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">sub 3</a></li>
         </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a href="#">menu 3 </a></li>
</ul>
```